# How to loop through document and find words from predefined array and replace each word with words from another array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I want to loop word document and find words from arrayOne.

for example

```
arrayOne = ["john", "jack", "dog"]
```

and each word that matches to replace with words from arrayTwo

```
arrayTwo = ["ana", "tanja", "cat"]
```

Comment: Seriously, though, this is not a forum for outsourcing code.  What have you tried and what specific question do you have about the code?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in asking a question.

Comment: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. I'm gonna keep in mind your suggestion. Actually, this is my first question in stackoverflow.com and it is possible that I made mistake. I'm gonna provide code next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not supplied any code with issues so there is nothing to fix, however you have asked 'How to find words and replace them'

Below are the steps you will need to code to achieve this: -

1. Build your array

   ```
   Dim AryFNR(1,2) As String
   AryFNR(0,0) = "john"
   AryFNR(1,0) = "ana"
   AryFNR(0,1) = "jack"
   AryFNR(1,1) = "tanja"
   ...
   ```
2. Connect to the document

   ```
   Dim WdDoc As Document
   Set WdDoc = ThisDocument
       ...
   Set WdDoc = Nothing
   ```
3. Connect to the selection ensuring it is in the connected document

   ```
   Dim WdSlct As Selection
   WdDoc.Content.Select
   Set WdSlct = Selection
       WdSlct.SetRange 0, 0
       ....
   Set WdSlct = Nothing
   ```
4. Connect to Find and Replace and clear previous settings

   ```
   Dim WdFnd As Find
   Set WdFnd = WdSlct.Find
       WdFnd.ClearAllFuzzyOptions
       WdFnd.ClearFormatting
       ...
   Set WdFnd = Nothing
   ```
5. Process your array using WdFnd on each item

   ```
   Dim LngCounter As Long
   For LngCounter = 0 To Ubound(AryFNR,2)
       With WdFnd
           .Execute FindText:=AryFNR(0, LngCounter), ReplaceWith:=AryFNR(1, LngCounter)
       End With
   Next
   ```

Some points you'll want to watch out for: -

- Footnotes and Endnotes are not processed unless the selection in the Footnote/Endnote.
- There are extra values on the `.Execute` command that you will want to set, depending on how you code it `.Found` may be useful.

That is enough information for you to start your own code to achieve your goal, enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for very helpful answer.

Comment: @EnisJasarovic I couldn't given you the answer outright as you hadn't done any of the code to start (or you hadn't posted it at least). I have done all I can to answer your question, if you feel if I given you the information to answer please could you mark this as correct.

Comment: See, for example: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/18814-how-find-replace-several-items-once.html, http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/40666-remove-stacking-fractions.html#post134542, http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/12803-find-replace.html#post34254. Each example is progressively more elaborate.